# Keep the root activity even after starting new activity and clearing the back stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, activity-stack

I will be starting activities in the following series:

A->B->C->D
Now I want to start another activity suppose E from D and clear the stack but keep activity A as root activity.
After starting E the stack should be A->E. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Popping off the Activity Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517063/android-popping-off-the-activity-stack)

Comment: @matoni this not duplicate. The one you have referred is telling about clearing the task. Here I am asking about start an activity and clear the stack still the root activity should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive that with [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html). This dude lets you rebuild stack which you need. You need somethink like this:

```
final Intent activityAIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
activityAIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                .addNextIntent(activityAIntent)
                .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, ActivityE.class))
                .startActivities();
```

Answer (score 0):

When your start activity E from D first clear flag top Or finishAffinity(). So all your previous activity is closed. and open first activity from backpress.

Add OnBackPressed method in E Activity.

Like this

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            finishAffinity();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```