# How to get home Screen on click of a Tab in Android

Tags: android, tabs

Suppose I have Two tabs Tab1 and Tab2
and three activities in Tab1 A,B,C
now user navigated to A->B->C
now if I am in Activity C and I click on Tab1 how will I move back to Activity A?

I want it to function same as iPhone i.e when user clicks on tab he is back to Home screen of that Tab.

Edit: Am using ActivityGroup

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of question like 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338841/how-to-clear-current-activities-in-the-stack) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408388/how-to-kill-sub-activities-and-bring-activity-to-top-of-stack)

might be this helps you

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Removes other Activities from stack
startActivity(intent);
```

if you want to load the old state you need to save it first.

Comment: Thanks, but where I will put this code if I am in same tab ? I checked with onTabChangeListener but its not triggered when you are in same tab ?

Comment: try to call the previous activity in the same way as you call the next within the tab in activity group

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 3 activities in one tab. Instead you should use a fragment in your tab and add or remove fragments in the stack.

I suggest you to use 3 fragments in a container and call `replace` on a [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) with your first fragment when you when to come back to initial state.

Comment: I am using Activity Group instead of fragments