# Android popping activities off the stack - yes, again

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app that starts a sequence of dialog-themed activities and I want to be able to pop them all off at once and go back to the main activity. I looked over existing questions like:

[How to clear current activities in the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338841/how-to-clear-current-activities-in-the-stack)

[how to kill sub activities and bring activity to top of stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408388/how-to-kill-sub-activities-and-bring-activity-to-top-of-stack)

[Android Popping off the Activity Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517063/android-popping-off-the-activity-stack)

And based on that came up with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This works functionally, but the problem I have is that when this is executed, the screen behind the dialog-themed activity turns black for a second before finally animating the dialogs off the screen. If I pop these activities manually with a back button this does not happen.

In LogCat I can see that when I pop the dialogs using the `Intent` method above, the main activity is destroyed and re-created, whereas when I just use the back button, the `onDestroy` and `onCreate` methods do not run. Is there any way to prevent the main activity from being explicitly re-started this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `singleTop` to your main activity.

Here, read about it. It brings the existing instance of the activity rather than create a new one.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Answer (score 0):

What about if you, when you add your main activity to the backstack you add it with a tag other than null like:

```
transaction.addToBackStack("welcome");
```

And then you can just pop the backstack like such:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack("welcome", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```